# Test an abstract class having constructor with arguments

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have to test one of my abstract classes which is implementing one of the interfaces.
The abstract class is having a constructor with arguments.
I am using Mockito as the testing framework.
So if I need to call the methods in the abstract class, what should be the best method?

If I try to subclass the abstract class, its asking to implement the argument constructor and not allowing a no-arg constructor to be written.
Also if I try to mock a class without a no-arg constructor, and put sysouts in the methods, usually I cannot see them invoked (Should the mocked class need a mandatory no-arg constructor ?) although there is no junit failure.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the abstract class arguments constructor protected ? also I am assuming that you are calling parameterized super from subclass otherwise you'll be getting compile time error. Could you post the code? as indicated by @Ralph best way is to implement concrete subclass, and normally its the ultimate descendent that you implement if you've multiple  abstract class in hierarchy. Which is also not error proof as you go by assumption that none of the abstract class has overridden method from parent. In that case you need to test both parent and overridden method.

Answer (score 2):

One way to test abstract classes is to implement a concreate subclass of it, only for testing.

If the abstract class has only a construtor with arguments you could do different things:

- pass null to its arguments
- pass mocked objects to its arguments
- pass concrete objects to its arguments

which way you choose depends on your test case and on the implementation of the abstract class. - Of course you could mix the ways.

Example:

```
abstract class A{
  A(Object o) {
  }
}

class TheNullWay extends A {
  TheNullWay() {
    super(null);
  }
}

class TheMockedWay extends A {
  TheMockedWay(Object o){
    super(o);
  }
}

new TheMockedWay(createMockedObject());
```

BTW: it is a complete different thing to test a class that uses the abstract class.